# How to set hash to empty?

Tags: vue-router

I will set hash to the property of variable `to`

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  to.hash = '';
});
```

And it given this error:

```
keycloak.js?ff98:24 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'hash' of object '#<Object>'
    at Object.eval [as successCallback] (keycloak.js?ff98:24)
    at Object.setSuccess (keycloak.js?68ad:1030)
    at Object.eval [as successCallback] (keycloak.js?68ad:133)
    at Object.setSuccess (keycloak.js?68ad:1030)
    at authSuccess (keycloak.js?68ad:630)
    at XMLHttpRequest.req.onreadystatechange (keycloak.js?68ad:603)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd actually just want to set mode to `"history"`.

```
const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history"
})
```

Make sure your server is configured to handle these links, though. https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/history-mode.html

Comment: It could not helped.

Comment: Helps for me this: ``` router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
        if (!this.isEmpty(to.hash))
             next({ params: to.params, path: to.path, query: to.query });
        else next();
});```